# Why is my cited url being changed?

Tags: discussion, moderation

https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/76351/revisions

The linked "issue has been addressed" has never been implemented, basically ignored and even pointed out as a non issue by the CM:

> What's the real harm here? It's not like the mobile page is *unusable* on desktop browsers. – Shog9♦ Jul 16 '15 at 21:03

[Automatically convert links to popular mobile pages (such as the mobile Wikipedia) to point to the corresponding regular pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260843/automatically-convert-links-to-popular-mobile-pages-such-as-the-mobile-wikipedi#comment850521_260843)

Why does the mod insist on targeting my posts for made up issues? While also using sarcasm in comments (`Until then, common sense prevails`)? I'm sure that's not compliant with the "be nice" policy, as usual.

Comment: Oh, and now another post has a "reference required" notice. I can only wonder what that's about. Funny how only my posts get those notices when there are tons of answers with no references that dont.

Comment: Maybe you could address the actual issues in the question, the veiled insult that says I don't have common sense, I'm sure moderators are held to the be nice policy right?, and the lock to the answer over something even Shog sees as harmless.

Comment: I honestly don't see why you're being so belligerent about this.  Another user (Napoleon) as many users would do fixed the link that you added.  It really wasn't clickable in the original form and in your rollbacks.  The fact that this resulted in a tusle over whether to use the desktop or mobile version seems a petty excuse for an argument to be honest. What Shog9 says can be read either way ... what's the harm here really in what he was doing?

Comment: @iandotkelly even if I copy paste that link and try to open it, I can't. I don't see any issue at all here.

Comment: @iandotkelly what's the harm in my link? He's just looking to start problems for problems sake.

Comment: @cde did you even checked your link at all?

Comment: The link wasn't clickable .... really.  The fact that it also switched to the desktop version too, is that really 'starting problems'?  Please don't take offense where clearly none is meant.

Comment: en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollywood is the valid link.

Comment: @iandotkelly maybe he shouldn't start problems where there is none. I was in the middle of expanding that answer when he started.

Comment: @cde you even know that you didn't had "wiki" in your first form of post, you just creating chaos over a wrong incomplete information

Comment: He was making it a hyperlink, not just the text of the url that you'd have to cut and paste into your browser address bar.  As for 'starting problems' ... seriously, as a user with over 50k reputation on this site and significant reputation elsewhere, you understand that it is collaboratively edited by other users.

Comment: @iandotkelly Why not make my fixed link a hyperlink then? Why continue to change it?

Comment: Please don't accuse me of making stuff up.  I'm clearly stating that he both made it a hyperlink AND changed it to the desktop version of the wikipedia link.  My point about the latter was 'what is the real harm here?' argument that Shog9 also applies here.  Accusing someone of deliberately starting something - when all they are doing is minimally editing your post is really going too far.

Comment: Anyway - I'm done with this for now - unfortunately it is late, and really it's becoming chat and should be moved there should the conversation continue.

Comment: @iandotkelly so explain the insult, and the locking. If it's so minimal, that's a trivial edit and that's discouraged. If it's so minimal, why go through all the trouble simply to antagonize me?

Comment: @cde what about you first rollback? Are you ever going to talk about that?

Comment: @cde "en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollywood is the valid link" - no it's not. Your URI is missing the scheme.  Some browsers will add `http://` or `https://` but not all. Please read [Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.google.com/search?q=Request+for+Comments+%28RFC%29+2396&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab).

Answer (score 12):

Your link did not work. An editor fixed it. Thank them and stop being a jackass about this.

Also, please don't quote me in irrelevant situations. It is rude. Thank you.

Comment: I quoted you in the exact situation that was happening. From the link that Napoleon provided as justification for changing the mobile wikipedia link that I used as a source. But ok. I won't. Consider it ended.

Comment: Go look at the first, 3rd, 4th revisions of your post. I did. The link straight up did not work. Fixing broken links is an admirable edit. Thank the editor for their time.

Comment: Mobile web edit system isn't as seamless as the desktop version. The 4th has the fixed link en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollywood

Comment: I do half my job on mobile. When I make a mistake and someone else fixes it, I thank them. That's just good manners.

Answer (score 10):

Your [original post](https://movies.stackexchange.com/revisions/76351/1):

[image]

Response of the link you used :

[image]

Napoleon fixed that link while making it desktop version too but you roll-backed it and fixed mobile link later. You just rollbacked a valid edit there.

[image]

Shog's comment doesn't say to not fix broken links.

Comment: You intentionally left out the wiki in the url https://movies.stackexchange.com/revisions/76351/4

Comment: And that statement is true, the "warning" is clear.

Comment: @cde [that's your doing](https://movies.stackexchange.com/revisions/76351/1), I gave screenshot of your own hand written post. Check first rivison,

Comment: Its untrue that you're not allowed to add a citation to a post.  The fact that one user edited your citation on another post (primarily to fix the broken link) does not mean you can't add a citation here or explain why you are not doing so.  There is no need for all this drama really.

Comment: And why you rollback napolepn's edit when you corrected that same mistake later on yourself.

Comment: Not to fix a broken link. Because it was fixed and he still changed it twice and locked the post and threatened me via moderator message over it.

Comment: @cde explain your first rollback

Comment: Explain the insult first.

Comment: And shog's comment is saying that there is no problem with them in the first place. Nothing to fix.

Comment: @cde your first link didn't had "wiki", I gave you secreenshot and link but you are still keeping your eyes shut and repeating same line again and again.

Comment: @cde use "contact us" if you feel so threatened by getting your not hyper-linked non working link getting fixed.